# Opencv Continously Tracking a Blinking Object C++

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

I have an object that lights up a certain color, say blue. It then blinks a different color every 5 seconds, say red. I have written a program to track the object using color based detection and draw a circle over it using opencv, but every time the object blinks red, I momentarily lose the ability to track it because the computer no longer sees the object. My question is, can I continuously track the blue object and have my program recognize the object as blue even while it is blinking red?

Code:
Note: I have an "object" class that has getters/setters for color, hsv min and max for its color, name, etc. trackObject() uses findContours method to track and draw graphics on the object.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  resizeWindow("trackbar", 500, 0);
  VideoCapture stream1(0);
  if (!stream1.isOpened()) {
    cout << "cannot open camera";
  }

  while (true) {
    Mat cameraFrame;
    Mat hsvFrame;
    Mat binMat;
    Mat grey;
    Mat grayBinMat;
    stream1.read(cameraFrame);
    if (cameraFrame.empty()) {
        break;
  }

    object blue("BLUE");
    cvtColor(cameraFrame, hsvFrame, CV_BGR2HSV, 0);
    inRange(hsvFrame, blue.getHSVMin(), blue.getHSVMax(), binMat);
    morphOps(binMat);
    trackobject(cameraFrame, binMat, blue);

    object red("RED");
    cvtColor(cameraFrame, hsvFrame, CV_BGR2HSV, 0);
    inRange(hsvFrame, red.getHSVMin(), red.getHSVMax(), binMat);
    morphOps(binMat);
    trackobject(cameraFrame, binMat, red);

    imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
    //imshow("gray bin", grayBinMat);
    imshow("hsv bin", binMat);
    imshow("hsv", hsvFrame);

    //1. waitKey waits (x ms) before resuming program 2. returns the ascii value of any key pressed during the wait time
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) {
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the object moving? If it is blue for 5 seconds, how many seconds is it red? What methods are you using to track the object? Can you adapt your detection code to track red objects?

Comment: Yes, it is moving. It blinks red for less than a second. I convert the video feed to hsv, then use inrange to isolate the blue color. Once it is isolated, I use findContours on the binary Mat output and Moments to get its x/y position. Yes I can adapt the code to track red.

Comment: Without seeing any code, I'd guess the simplest solution would be to modify your detection function to include a backup red search if your blue search fails to find the object. If speed is an issue you might limit the search region to some derivative of the last detected blue position. You could also include a bool switch `do_blue_first` that you could change when the color changes, which would reduce the number of double searches that occur.

Comment: Problem is, each color represents something. For example, while tracking the blue object, I would write "blue" over it, but when it changes color, my red object tracking code executes and writes "red" over it. I want to keep "blue" over the object even when it flashes red. I put some code up for your reference.

Comment: Then your question isn't really about how to track the object but about the logic of your program. Which I would implement as such: 1. Detect blue object; 2. If blue not detected, detect red; 3. Track; 4. Draw based on which detector fired. As BHawk suggested, if you want to speed it up even further, you can extend the search window around the last known position instead of the whole image.

Comment: I have a red and blue object detector because there are red and blue objects on screen, and the blue object flashes red. The issue is that when blue flashes red, the red detector fires and the computer thinks there is another red object and writes "red" over that object. I want to overwrite that code so that the computer writes "blue" even when the blue object flashes red. In other words, I want to disregard the momentary change in color and continue writing "blue" over the object.

Comment: That is new and important information. Can you include a frame where the blue object is blue and another frame where the blue object is red? It seems like tracking a blue object that is not always blue based on color is the wrong method of tracking. Perhaps there is something else unique about the blue object (shape, relative size, luminance, motion patterns) that might be used to separate it from the others. It is hard to recommend other tracking methods without knowing the full context or seeing the images and/or the motion.

Comment: The object is small, cylindrical, and emits colored light from the top face. Because the object emits light, it has a high luminance, which makes it easy to isolate in grayscale, and it shouldn't be a problem to implement grayscale based object tracking. However, this won't help me differentiate between colors. I am wondering if it is possible to detect the blue color and write "blue" over the object even if it briefly flashes red.